# Mechanize won't conect to site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

Welcome, I got a problem, gem mechanize won't connect to a site. Gem is installed. 
Code:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
main_page = agent.get 'https://imbd.com'
main_page.link_with(text: "Top 250").click
rows = list_page.root.css(".lister-list tr")

puts rows.size
```

And this is an error:

```
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) for "imbd.com" port 80 (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:73:in `timeout'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:858:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:700:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:631:in `connection_for'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:994:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.4/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:267:in `fetch'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.4/lib/mechanize.rb:464:in `get'
    from C:/Ruby/Workspace/imbd.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

**Anyone has any idea what's wrong? Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's true that mechanize doesn't support javascript, your problem is that you are trying to access a site that doesn't exist.  You are trying to access `www.imbd.com` instead of `www.imdb.com`.  So, the error message is accurate.

And FWIW, [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/conditions) doesn't want you to scrape their site:

> Robots and Screen Scraping: You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below.

Comment: Didn't know about it. I'm only scraping 10 titles from their database. Only for edu purposes, not commerce or spam :) Thanks for that misspell, now I'm just dumb. Looked for error in other parts of code.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at imdb I see they're running heavy amounts of javascript which will trip Mechanize up since it can't parse js and understand the incoming response.  I would suggest using Capybara instead of Mechanize if you're looking to scrape the content or automate browsing.  Combining Capybara with something like Poltergeist (you'll need to install phantom.js with this approach) will work far better than Mechanize and is built for automating interaction with pages loading lots of js.

I added a way to maybe work around the error for you.  If this works it's because Mechanize was trying to get the page before the js scripts were done and therefore not getting valid data.

Edit:

```
  agent = Mechanize.new
  agent.read_timeout=3  #set the agent time out
  begin
  main_page = agent.get 'https://imbd.com'
  main_page.link_with(text: "Top 250").click
  rows = list_page.root.css(".lister-list tr")
  rescue Timeout::Error 
    puts "Timeout!"
    puts "read_timeout attribute is set to #{agent.read_timeout}s" if !agent.read_timeout.nil?
  end
```

Comment: I saw on one tutorial that Mechanize handled imbd page in this exact way and I struggle with it... damn.

Comment: Link me the tutorial, could be outdated.  I used to rely on Mechanize for scraping however now with the resurgence of js sites everywhere I've had to start using Capybara & Poltergeist and couldn't be happier.